# Returning rows with 0 count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Attempting to return the number of staff that has been booked to work a specific event by using a count function on `tblEmployeeBooking` ; This value will be used as a comparison against the number of staff required from `tblEvent`.

Currently, the below statement doesn't return any `tblEvent` records which have a zero count within `tblEmployeeBooking`

```
SELECT e.eventID
     , e.staffQuantity
     , Count(b.eventID) AS CountOfeventID
  FROM tblEmployeeBooking b
  LEFT 
  JOIN tblEvent e 
    ON b.eventID = e.eventID
GROUP 
    BY e.eventID
     , e.staffQuantity
     , b.cancelled
HAVING (((b.cancelled)=0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use `RIGHT JOIN` or switch the order of the tables in your `LEFT JOIN`. When you use `LEFT JOIN`, it selects all matching rows from the left table, it's the right table that's allowed to have non-matches in the `ON` condition.

Also, you need to move any conditions on the table that could have missing rows into the `ON` clause. Testing them in `WHERE` or `HAVING` will filter out those rows because columns are all `NULL` when there's no match, and that doesn't `= 0`.

And you shouldn't use any columns from the child table in `GROUP BY`, because when there's no match those columns will all be `NULL`, and they'll group together. In this case, there's no point in grouping by `tblEmployeeBooking.cancelled` because you're only selecting rows where `cancelled = 0`, so they'll all be in the same group anyway.

So it should be:

```
SELECT tblEvent.eventID, tblEvent.staffQuantity, Count(tblEmployeeBooking.eventID) AS CountOfeventID
FROM tblEvent
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeBooking ON tblEmployeeBooking.eventID = tblEvent.eventID AND tblEmployeeBooking.cancelled = 0
GROUP BY tblEvent.eventID, tblEvent.staffQuantity
```

Comment: And aliases are brilliant

Comment: @Strawberry I usually use short aliases in my answers, but in this case it was too easy to just cut and paste his query and rearrange it, so I didn't feel like replacing all the table names with aliases.

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you for your help.